# Arduino-like Platform With Wireless and Video?

Tags: arduino, wireless, video

Is there a Arduino-like hardware platform that allows for wireless connectivity (think remote control) and for connection of a webcam (with streaming that wireless video over the wireless connection)?

I really like the idea of a prebuilt hardware platform and would be interested in getting into robotics. Since I am already a proficient programmer, it would be great to take this into the physical world as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your best bet would be a Linux based system. Something like Beagle Board.

Arduinos and their ilk tend to target low cost microcontrollers.

In order to stream video over a wireless connection, you're going to need a fast processor and a fast wireless link. I'd pick an ARM based system, running Linux with WiFi.

Here's an example of what can be done with a BeagleBoard:
http://mechomaniac.com/OpenCVBallTracking

Comment: Very cool, I'll look into it :)

Comment: @Andrew - While Joby's answer is a good one, you'll have more and better answers if you wait a while before accepting an answer.  48 hours is generally a reasonable amount of time to wait.  There are lots of other takes on this problem than this one.

Comment: I agree with reemrevnivek

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Bug Labs gear - they've got some modules for Wifi, video, 3G and such. http://www.buglabs.net/products